# Size and resolution in photoshop for 10.0 inch android tablet

Tags: android, photoshop

I am making an image in photoshop for a 10.0 inch android tablet (500x413px, resolution of 300), but this is distorted by the tablet.
 I'd like to know the proper size and resolution for the image in photoshop. 
I'd like to know the proper size and resolution
for the image in photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look here: [andrioid Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/device-frames.html)

You can generate framed android pictures.

It specifies the size of image you need. for each device type.

The motorola XZoom 10" is  @ 160dpi 800x1280

Note: Other 10" Devices may vary in size and shape